# How to insert a php array into another array

Tags: php, arrays

Coming from a javascript background, I'm having a little difficulty inserting a php array into another array.

If I have the following:

```
$common_properties = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'eats' => array(
        'apples' => true,
        'oranges' => true
    )
);

$one = array(
    'name' => 'one',
    'desc' => 'Lorem'
);

$two = array(
    'name' => 'two',
    'desc' => 'Ipsum'
);
```

How can I make the `$common_properties` array accessible from `$one` and `$two`? I need to pass the resulting array(s) as arguments to a function. For some reason, array_merge resulted in an error.

The desired result should be, for example:

```
$one = array(
    'name' => 'one',
    'desc' => 'Lorem'
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'eats' => array(
        'apples' => true,
        'oranges' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what is your final desired result? What did you try and what was your error?

Comment: @MihaiIorga - yes, my bad - please see amendment for the desired result.

Comment: what do you mean `array_merge()` resulted into an error, i think you can just straight up merge them using that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$one = array_merge($one, $common_properties);

print_r($one);
/* ⇨
Array
(
    [name] => one
    [desc] => Lorem
    [foo] => bar
    [eats] => Array
        (
            [apples] => 1
            [oranges] => 1
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: Ah - I'd previously attempted to pass the entire array_merge function as the argument. php really isn't quite as forgiving as javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the below to add `$common_properties` to `$one` and `$two`

`$one['commonProperties'] = $common_properties;`

`$two['commonProperties'] = $common_properties;`

You can then pass the two arrays (`$one` and `$two`) to your method like so `function_name($one, $two)`

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that if you need to change array properties in $common_properties and have them reflect globally then you might want to assign by reference.  Assign by value is fine for read-only or cases where it doesn't matter if $one and $two have different values, but if the state needs to remain in sync than =& is a better choice than =

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately this doesn't yield the desired result. Please see the edit with the output I need.